# Issue with JSON.net anyOf schema validation

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I'm using the [JSON.Net schema validation package](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) and I've come across a very strange issue. I have tracked down the issue to a use of `anyOf` in the `anyObject` definition below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/schemas/example/1.0/schema.json",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/anyObject"
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "anyObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "typeA"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/typeA"
          },
          "else": false
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "typeB"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/typeB"
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "bodyDefinition": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "$computed": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "$computed"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/computedBody"
          },
          "else": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/wildcardBody"
          }
        },
        {
            "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "wildcardBody": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
      }
    },
    "firstComputedValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "$computed": {
          "const": "first"
        },
        "values": {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "$computed",
        "values"
      ]
    },
    "computedBody": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "$computed": {
                "const": "first"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/firstComputedValue"
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "typeA": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "typeA"
        },
        "body": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ]
    },
    "typeB": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "typeB"
        },
        "body": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I test this json:

```
{
  "type": "typeB",
  "body":{
     "$computed":"first",
     "values":[]
  }
}
```

It *should* be marked as invalid, because `values` is required to have at least one value. However it is valid. The below JSON should be considered valid, and the above schema does assert that correctly:

```
{
  "type": "typeB",
  "body":{
     "$computed":"first",
     "values":["foo"]
  }
}
```

If I remove `typeA` from the `anyObject` definition, then the validation is performed correctly. Below is the schema that validates correctly:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/schemas/example/1.0/schema.json",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/anyObject"
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "anyObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "type": {
                "const": "typeB"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/typeB"
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "bodyDefinition": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "$computed": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "$computed"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/computedBody"
          },
          "else": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/wildcardBody"
          }
        },
        {
            "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },
    "wildcardBody": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
      }
    },
    "firstComputedValue": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "$computed": {
          "const": "first"
        },
        "values": {
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "$computed",
        "values"
      ]
    },
    "computedBody": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "$computed": {
                "const": "first"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/firstComputedValue"
          },
          "else": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "typeA": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "typeA"
        },
        "body": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ]
    },
    "typeB": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "typeB"
        },
        "body": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/bodyDefinition"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone see if there is an issue with this definition, or is this an issue with the JSON.Net schema package?

This testing was done against the online version of the schema validator at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug. I'll speak to the library author about it!

To debug, I followed the validation process through the schema, setting `$ref` or `then` or `else` to `false`... when I reached `computedBody`, I changed it to the following...

```
"computedBody": {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "$computed": {
            "const": "first"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": false,
      "else": false
    }
```

Validation still comes back positive, which shouldn't be possible. I proved it reaches `computedBody` by setting that subschema to `false` and seeing validation come back negative.

(the `oneOf` wrapping the subschema of `computedBody` isn't needed. `if` is valid at the schema level just fine).

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. Yeah, this example is a little contrived, as I was trying to get a minimal example for reproduction to post. The actual `computedBody` has several other options in. Thanks for speaking to the library author!

Comment: I'm tweeted them and invited them to join the JSON Schema slack to discuss (this and something else). Will see what happens. =] Is there an official support forum as it's a paid for product?

Comment: There, is, and I have emailed them, providing a link to this question, however you got there first!

Comment: I have had a response from James Newton-King. He has tracked down the issue and will be publishing a fix in the next couple of days.